# How can I display a message to the user after they request a new password on my Drupal-based site?

Tags: drupal, passwords, message, alert, reset

I work primarily with WordPress sites, and I have minimal experience with Drupal. Only about 1/100 of my sites use it, so I usually don't need to worry about it.

Right now, however, I need to add an alert after a user requests a new password on a Drupal based site. The alert is to tell the user that they need to check their email for the new password. It doesn't even need to be a popup, the message just has to be there.

I've been wandering aimlessly through the site's files and backend and all across google but I can't find any solutions to this. A solution would be great but I'd appreciate it if anyone could even point me in the right direction to figure it out myself. Please help!

Edit:
I have checked the triggers page and there is nothing there that can help. I also read about a module called password_trigger which sends an email alert. The site is set up to send an email already, but it's not using this module. Help?

Answer (score 2):

If that is not showing, double check that `<?php print $messages; ?>` is in your page.tpl.php theme file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this won't happen by default?

I just went to one of my Drupal 7 sites and did this:

- clicked Request new password
- typed in my user name
- clicked Email New Password

Drupal displayed a message that said

> Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address

Does that not happen for you? (If not, which version of Drupal are you using?)

I'm not clear about the email part of your question. Is Drupal sending out an email to the user when a new password is requested?

Comment: The site is using Drupal 6.13. Is the message supposed to be displayed in this version by default?

And yes, the email is being sent. Just no message on the site.

Comment: Yep, the message should be displayed by default in Drupal 6 as well as Drupal 7. I just tested it in Drupal 6 and I got the same message after requesting a new password ("Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address.") What happens if you switch to a default theme (Garland) and request a new password - do you see the message then?